# Issue while passing null values to nullable properties in web api call in .netcore web api project

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-core-webapi

I am facing issue while passing null parameter values to properties of my model in HttpGet verb.

I am using .Net Core 2.1 for my web API project. Below is my action method in controller:

```
    [HttpGet("get")]
    public ActionResult GetData([FromQuery]MyTestModel model)
    {
        var result = new MyTestModel();
        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

And my MyTestModel.cs is like :

```
 [Serializable]
public class MyTestModel
{
    public MyTestModel()
    {
        PageNo = 1;
        PageSize = 10;
    }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int? CandidateId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

When I call the API like :

```
api/controller/get?clientId=7583&candidateId=null&fromDate=null&toDate=null
```

I am getting 400 response. Below is the response message:

```
{"toDate":["The value 'null' is not valid for ToDate."],
 "fromDate":["The value 'null' is not valid for FromDate."],
 "candidateId":["The value 'null' is not valid for CandidateId."]
}
```

When I don't send nullable properties at all(candidateId, fromDate,toDate), this hits my action and uses default values as null.

What's the problem if I am trying to explicitly setting null values?

Do I need to set some configuration in my Startup.cs to handle null values for nullable properties?

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to just omit the value (and everything is sent as text, and converted to the type by the ModelBinder - there is no conversion from "null" to `null`)

Comment: You don't need to do `fromDate=null`. You just don't pass the values if you want to send them as null. When you do `fromDate=null` it takes "null" as string value and tries to assign to the property. that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, is there any way to handle null values? I am just curious to know the solution. I knew the alternative by just omitting the null values from request.

Comment: Do you mean by using `&candidateId=null`? You would need to create a custom ModelBinder, (or a ValueProvider might also be an option). Note also an empty string translates to `null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything sent in the query string is just a string. So, when you do something like `toDate=null`, you're actually saying "set `toDate` to `"null"`", i.e. the *string* "null". The modelbinder attempts to convert all the strings to the actual types you're binding to, but there's no conversion available that can turn `"null"` into a null `DateTime`.

To set the value to `null`, you need to either pass no value `toDate=` or just omit the key entirely from the query string.